# Sorting a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm starting with this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Author':['Alice','Bob','Alice','Bob','Charlie','Charlie'],'Book':['book1','book1','book2','book2','book3','book4']})
```

I'd like to sort it to find unique authors with unique books, and I want to exclude co-authors. So, the result would be the following DataFrame:

```
{'Author':['Alice','Charlie'],'Book':['book1','book3']}
```

I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
subset = df.groupby('Book').first().reset_index().groupby('Author').first().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
    Author   Book
0    Alice  book1
1  Charlie  book3
```